# query execution error in php

Tags: php, sql-server-2005

I am creating a report using php and back end sql server 2005. i write the blew query this run fine in sql server while giving error when executing in php.

```
$query = "select distinct t1.VisitDate,t1.ReceiptNo,t1.VisitorNo,p.PatientName,STUFF((
    SELECT f.Particular + ', ' from CollectionPointTable t2,FeesTable f 
    where t1.ReceiptNo = t2.ReceiptNo and f.ID = t2.TestID 
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,0,'') Tests , sum(t1.payment) as Amount 
    from CollectionPointTable t1,patientinformationtable p 
    where  p.visitorno = t1.visitorno and convert(varchar(10),t1.VisitDate,103) = '$date' 
    group by t1.Receiptno,p.patientname,t1.VisitorNo,t1.VisitDate 
    order by ReceiptNo";

$stid = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);
$Today_patient_list = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stid,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
```

That is the error which gives by Error

> Warning: sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wampnew\www\logs\viewTodaysCollection.php on line 65

Comment: Will you please first check your sqlsrv_connect? Does your connection is completed?

Comment: `sqlsrv_query` may have returned an error. Check its return value before using `$stid` in `fetch_array`. (Maybe there is an error in your `$query`)

Comment: check the value of`$stid` by printing it out using `var_dump` and you will see that it is Boolean type

Comment: yes i checked $stid and returen error i.e  Array

Comment: checked by var_dump and returned bool(false)

Answer (score 0):

```
Use the following code, it should work:
$query = "select distinct t1.VisitDate,t1.ReceiptNo,t1.VisitorNo,p.PatientName,STUFF((
    SELECT f.Particular + ', ' from CollectionPointTable t2,FeesTable f 
    where t1.ReceiptNo = t2.ReceiptNo and f.ID = t2.TestID 
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,0,'') Tests , sum(t1.payment) as Amount 
    from CollectionPointTable t1,patientinformationtable p 
    where  p.visitorno = t1.visitorno and convert(varchar(10),t1.VisitDate,103) = '$date' 
    group by t1.Receiptno,p.patientname,t1.VisitorNo,t1.VisitDate 
    order by ReceiptNo";

$stid = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);
$Today_patient_list = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stid);
```

Comment: the query output have coma (,) in one field value , when i removed this column then it run fine.